q 82 of Random Variable from Sheldon Ross book
The Question is- A purchaser of transistors buys them in lots of $20$. It is
his policy to randomly inspect 4 components from a lot and
to accept the lot only if all 4 are non-defective. If each com-
ponent in a lot is, independently, defective with probability
$.1$, what proportion of lots is rejected?
After searching on internet I got the following solution
In this case, we are looking for the probability that at least one of the $4$ transistors inspected is defective. This is equivalent to $1$ minus the probability that all $4$ transistors are non-defective.
Let's calculate:
$n = 4$ (number of transistors inspected)
$p = 0.1$ (probability that a transistor is defective)
$k = 0$ (we want all transistors to be non-defective)
$$P(X=0) = C(4, 0) * (0.1^0) * ((1-0.1)^{4-0})\\
  = 1 * 1 * (0.9^4)\\
  = 0.6561$$
The probability that all $4$ transistors are non-defective is $0.6561$. Therefore, the probability that at least one transistor is defective (and the lot is rejected) is $1 - 0.6561 = 0.3439$ or $34.39\%$.
So, the proportion of lots that is rejected is 34.39%.
**My Question is why doesn't he consider the probability of picking four transistor from a lot of 20 transistor then do the remaining calculation **

Please use MathJax whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part.

“It is his policy to randomly inspect 4 components from a lot". So there's no question or uncertainty about the number of transistors selected.

@MatthewLeingang There's no uncertainty about the number of transistors selected. But there is randomness in which four of the twenty are selected. OP's question is why this uncertainty isn't considered.

Which Sheldon Ross textbook does this question come from?

There are $C(20,4)$, or $\binom{20}{4}$ different samples of four that the inspector could choose. I believe you're asking why the uncertainty about which four are chosen wasn't considered in the problem. The reason is: It doesn't make a difference which four you choose. Let's prove this. We'll prove this in more generality.
Suppose that we have $N$ random variables and a measurable function $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, where $0<n<N$. Let $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set. Let $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n, X_1,\ldots, X_N$ be iid random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$.
Let $\Gamma=[N]^n$ be the set of all $n$-element subsets of $\{1,\ldots, N\}$. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the power set of $[N]^n$ and let $\gamma$ be the uniform measure on $[N]^n$. So for $G\in \Gamma$, $\gamma(G)=|G|/\binom{N}{n}$.
For a member $g$ of $\Gamma$ and $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$, let $g(i)$ be the $i^{th}$ smallest member of $g$. So $g=\{g(1),\ldots, g(n)\}$ and $g(1)<\ldots<g(n)$.
We can ignore the process of choosing $n$ variables from among the $X_1,\ldots, X_N$ and simply ask for $$\mathbb{P}(f(Y_1,\ldots, Y_n)\in B).$$ Or we can first choose $g\in \Gamma$ and ask for the probability $$\mathbb{P}(f(X_{g(1)},\ldots, X_{g(n)})\in B).$$ Then the total probability in this case is $$\sum_{g\in \Gamma} \mathbb{P}(f(X_{g(1)},\ldots, X_{g(n)})\in B)\gamma(g).$$ Here we're using the fact that which $g$ is chosen is independent of the $X_1,\ldots, X_N$ (whether or not an $i$ is chosen is independent of its value). But by assumption, $(X_{g(1)},\ldots, X_{g(n)})$ and $(Y_1,\ldots, Y_n)$ have the same distribution, so the total probability is \begin{align*} \sum_{g\in \Gamma} \mathbb{P}(f(X_{g(1)},\ldots, X_{g(n)})\in B)\gamma(g) & =\sum_{g\in \Gamma}\mathbb{P}(f(Y_1,\ldots, Y_n)\in B)\gamma(g) \\ & = \mathbb{P}(f(Y_1,\ldots, Y_n)\in B)\sum_{g\in \Gamma}\gamma(g) \\ & = \mathbb{P}(f(Y_1,\ldots, Y_n)\in B)\cdot 1 \\ & = \mathbb{P}(f(Y_1,\ldots, Y_n)\in B).\end{align*}
EDIT: In other words, let's pick four of the twenty transistors. Let $p$ be the probability that all four are non-defective.  We get the same $p$ no matter which four we choose.
Now let's include the uncertainty of picking four of twenty transistors. Suppose there are $N$ possible sets of $4$ (in this case, there are $C(20,4)$, but that doesn't matter), and they're all equally likely. Let $s_1,\ldots, s_N$ be the different sets of $4$ transistors. We pick an $i$, which happens with probability $1/N$, then check the probability that all four of the ones we chose are non-defective (probability $p$), and then sum this over all possible outcomes (all values of $i$). This gives $$\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{p}{N}=p\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{N}=p.$$  So the uncertainty in which four we choose doesn't matter.

Thank you 4 response you got my doubt but i am beginner in probability it will be great if you explain it in simple language briefly.Looking forward for ur response

I added a summary.
